# Google maps markers from xml working in Chrome, not Firefox/IE

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I've got a custom google map that loads a bunch of markers from an xml doc and creates a sidebar list of all the markers as well. It works fine in Chrome but but the sidebar and markers don't load in Firefox or IE. I'm using the latest versions of all browsers on a Windows7 machine.

--I edited this to add the xml parser code since that may be the problem. I don't even remember where I got this parser code but it has been(and still is) working fine on another project with pretty similar code.

javascript...

```
      var side_bar_html = ""; 

    var routes = {
     y: {
    name: "Winter Routes",
        url: "http://www.huts.org/Tests/Maps/GPSTracks/10thsystemHutsYurtsMap.kml"

    },


};

      var gmarkers = []; 


      var map = null;
// A function to create the marker and set up the event window function 
function createMarker(latlng, name, html) {
    var contentString = html;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        icon: 'images/marker2_ltblue.png',
        map: map,
        suppressInfoWindows: true,
        zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
        });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(contentString); 
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
        });

   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    // map.setZoom(9);
     map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
     });
    // save the info we need to use later for the side_bar
    gmarkers.push(marker);
    // add a line to the side_bar html
    side_bar_html += '<a href="javascript:myclick(' + (gmarkers.length-1) + ')" onmouseover="gmarkers['+ (gmarkers.length-1)  +'].setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE)" onmouseout="gmarkers['+ (gmarkers.length-1)  +'].setAnimation(null)">' + name + '<\/a><br>';
}

// This function picks up the click and opens the corresponding info window
function myclick(i) {
  google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[i], "click");
}

function initialize() {
  // create the map
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 9,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.369804, -106.388725),
    mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
    navigationControl: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
                                myOptions);

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.close();
        });
      // Read the data from example.xml
      downloadUrl("gMapsHuts.xml", function(doc) {
        var xmlDoc = xmlParse(doc);
        var markers = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          // obtain the attribues of each marker
          var lat = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat"));
          var lng = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"));
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
          var name = markers[i].getAttribute("label");
          var html = GXml.value(markers[i].getElementsByTagName("infowindow")[0]);
          var category = markers[i].getAttribute("category");
          var season = markers[i].getAttribute("season");
          // create the marker
          var marker = createMarker(point,name,html,category);
        }
        // put the assembled side_bar_html contents into the side_bar div
        document.getElementById("side_bar").innerHTML = side_bar_html;
      });
      createRouteTogglers();
    }

 // the important function... routes[id].xxxxx refers back to the top 
function toggleRoute(checked, id) {

    if (checked) {

        var layer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(routes[id].url, {
            preserveViewport: true,
            suppressInfoWindows: false 
        });
        // store kml as obj
        routes[id].obj = layer;
        routes[id].obj.setMap(map);
    }
    else {
        routes[id].obj.setMap(null);
        delete routes[id].obj;
    }

};

// create the Routes controls
function createRouteTogglers() {

    var html = "<form><ul>";
    for (var prop in routes) {
        html += "<li id=\"selector-" + prop + "\"><input type='checkbox' id='" + prop + "'" +
        " onclick='highlight(this,\"selector-" + prop + "\"); toggleRoute(this.checked, this.id)' \/>" +
        routes[prop].name + "<\/li>";
    }
    html += "<\/ul><\/form>";

    document.getElementById("routeLayers").innerHTML = html;
};

// Append Class on Select
function highlight(box, listitem) {
    var selected = 'selected';
    var normal = 'normal';
    document.getElementById(listitem).className = (box.checked ? selected: normal);
};
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
  { 
    size: new google.maps.Size(150,50)
  });
```

xml parser...

```
function GXml(){}
GXml.value=value;
GXml.parse=parse;

function value(node){
   if(!node){
      return"";
   }
   var retStr="";
   if(node.nodeType==3||node.nodeType==4||node.nodeType==2){
      retStr+=node.nodeValue;
   }else if(node.nodeType==1||node.nodeType==9||node.nodeType==11){
      for(var i=0;i<node.childNodes.length;++i){
         retStr+=arguments.callee(node.childNodes[i]);
      }
   }
   return retStr;
}


function parse(textDoc){
   try{
      if(typeof ActiveXObject!="undefined"&&typeof GetObject!="undefined"){
         var b=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
         b.loadXML(textDoc);
         return b;
      }else if(typeof DOMParser!="undefined"){
         return(new DOMParser()).parseFromString(textDoc,"text/xml");
      }else{
         return Wb(textDoc);
      }
   }
   catch(c){
      P.incompatible("xmlparse");
   }
   try{
      return Wb(textDoc);
   }
   catch(c){
      P.incompatible("xmlparse");
      return document.createElement("div");
   }
}

function P(){}
P.write=function(a,b){}
;P.writeRaw=function(a){}
;P.writeXML=function(a){}
;P.writeURL=function(a){}
;P.dump=function(a){}
;P.incompatible=function(){}
;P.clear=function(){}
;

function Wb(a){
   return null;
}
```

Comment: Probably an issue with browser specific behavior of the xml parser.  Hard to tell from what you posted.

Comment: I added the xml parser code above. I don't remember where i got this code from and am obviously still a newbie so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does your xml look like?  Is it "valid" in Firefox/IE (do they let you load it)?

Comment: Looks like it is, if it is this: [kml validation](http://feedvalidator.org/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.huts.org%2FTests%2FMaps%2FGPSTracks%2F10thsystemHutsYurtsMap.kml) or [this xml](http://www.huts.org/Tests/gMapsHuts.xml).  Looks like it wasn't valid, but you found the error and fixed it.